# Having Issue with Azure Cloud Service Web Role that points to SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio, azure, cloud

I'm having a weird problem with my web application when it is hosted on Azure.  Basically the issue is that I have one page that goes to the database and when my application's connection string points to my SQL Azure DB, I get a blank response for that particular page (By blank I mean when you view source you see absolutely nothing).  When I point to my normal SQL Server 2008 DB the page works fine.

On the development server and Azure development server using Visual Studio, I don't have any problems with the page when pointing to SQL Azure.

Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup firewall rules on SQL Azure to allow access.